# Calling detachNewThreadSelector:target:object: vs dispatch_async()

Tags: multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread, nsoperation

Pages 37 and 39 of Concurrency Programming Guide (PDF version) seem to be an in contradiction. In page 37, the code snippet specifies the following:

```
if (![anOp isConcurrent])
    [anOp start];
else
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(start) toTarget:anOp withObject:nil];
```

This looks fine, except that in page 39 the documentation states:

> You can use dispatch queues to perform nearly all of the tasks that
>   you used to perform on separate threads. The advantage of dispatch
>   queues is that they are simpler to use and much more efficient at
>   executing those tasks than the corresponding threaded code.

So instead of calling detachNewThreadSelector:target:object:, why isn't the code calling dispatch_async() instead?

Answer (score 0):

Ye I can see what you saying. I think that each way works but depending on the situation you should choose which root to go. Something to note is that `NSOperationQueues` are good to use; in mac osx they use `GCD` to optimise so they are a good choice. In iOS 4 and below they do not. So using `GCD` is something you should seriously consider if working on previous versions of iOS. If you dispatch a new `NSThread` the OS has to keep switching threads which can be a performance issue. `GCD` uses the pools approach, meaning that it will re use existing threads if it is good to do so.

Hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: Since iOS 4, NSOperationQueue uses GCD.

[NSOperationQueue Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)